# Autolayout invalid related to hidden navigationbar in xib

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on an problem related to navigation bar in xib file. The problem is as follows:

I add a xib file, and manually put a `UINavigationBar` on top of it, and use constraints to make it stays on top of the screen. Then I add a `UILabel` below it, and also use constraints to make it just below the navigation bar. That is, `let label.top` equals `navigationbar.bottom`. Then I need to add a fullscreen function. I add a button and after pressing it, I hide the navigation bar by code like this:

```
self.navbar.hidden = YES;
```

The navbar is hidden, but the label is somehow still keeping its position, and doesn't move to the top of the screen, which is what I expected to see.

So the question is:

1. Is this effect normal? Because now the navbar is hidden, the constraints should make the label move to top.
2. What should I do to achieve the effect I want if it's normal/abnormal.

Thank you guys! Any idea can help!

And pardon me for my English, for it's not my native language.

Comment: hiding the nav bar won't change it's position and so still label.top equals navigationbar.bottom even on hiding it.... you can add another constraint to the top with low priority... then on hiding navbar, change it's priority so it is now larger than the priority of constraint label.top equals navigationbar.bottom

Comment: Then should I manually set the label frame to make it top? Is there any automatic way? For in real project there are more than a label below it, and moving each control is too much work to do.

Comment: You can make a view to contain all those views, that way you only need to change one constraint... For navbar you don't have any automatic way.... for labels you have sizeToFit which can be used

Comment: create outlet of topspace constraint for label and change that constraint constant value when navigationbar hidden otherwise put as it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are just adding a navigation bar, not a navigation controller, so hiding wont work. You have to set height constraint on your navigation bar, and make its outlet in your controller, then where you want to hide the bar you have to set your constraint.constant to zero.

Answer (score 0):

you hide the navigation bar & set the frame of lable .

```
if(self.navbar.hidden){

   // set frame of lable on top aas you required ..

}
```

hope it help you.

Comment: Is there any automatic way? There may be other controls related to it, and I don't want to move each of them, the layout maybe very complex to manually calculate.

Comment: I think no because you just hide the navigation bar but bar is still present there so you set it manually .

Answer (score 0):

Create outlets of topspace constraint and height constraint for label and change that constraint constant value when navigationbar hidden  otherwise put as it is previously.

Example:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSLayoutConstraint *lblTopSpaceConstraintValue;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSLayoutConstraint *lblHeightConstraintValue;
and write condition 

if(self.navigationBar.hidden)
{

lblTopSpaceConstraintValue.constant = 0;
lblHeightConstraintValue.constant = 0;

}

else

{

lblTopSpaceConstraintValue.constant = 10;//label topspaceconstraint value which you have given previously
lblHeightConstraintValue.constant = 21; //label height constraint value which you have given previously

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I know exactly what should I do!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all! I set the height constraint of the navbar to zero, and it works fine! You guys just taught me a lot about the constraints, Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
Create IBIOutlet of label top Constraint with navbar. 

    IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint* _lblTopNavBarConstraint;

and set value as per the condition.

- (IBAction) move:(id)sender
{
    _navBar.hidden = !_navBar.hidden;
    _lblTopNavBarConstraint.constant = (_navBar.hidden) ? -20 : 20;
}
```